# Clonal Selection Algorithm to solve the traveling salesman problem

Tags: traveling-salesman

I'm attempting to implement a solution to the Traveling Salesman Problem using the a Clonal Selection ALgorithm. I'm doing it for a class project of mine to compare how Clonal Selection compares with a traditional Genetic Algorithm for this problem. I've found a paper of someone who has done this before at which I am attempting to reproduce.

http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~vonzuben/research/lnunes_dout/artigos/gecco00.pdf

The algorithm is explained in detail in section 5. Does anybody know the relationship between the Memory Set and the Population at each generation? Does the memory set replace the population at each generation? At each generation is it the Memory set that is cloned and mutated or is it the population?

Any help would be appreciated!